# unable to install virtual box on ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64

Tags: installation, virtualbox

I downloaded x64 version of VirtualBox from its official site as I am having Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 version.
Its of 64 MB .deb file.
Now when I try to install it, it is causing error.

> ```
> Package operation failed
> The installation or removal of a software package failed.
> (Reading database ... 
> (Reading database ... 5%
> (Reading database ... 10%
> (Reading database ... 15%
> (Reading database ... 20%
> (Reading database ... 25%
> (Reading database ... 30%
> (Reading database ... 35%
> (Reading database ... 40%
> (Reading database ... 45%
> (Reading database ... 50%
> (Reading database ... 55%
> (Reading database ... 60%
> (Reading database ... 65%
> (Reading database ... 70%
> (Reading database ... 75%
> (Reading database ... 80%
> (Reading database ... 85%
> (Reading database ... 90%
> (Reading database ... 95%
> (Reading database ... 100%
> (Reading database ... 145794 files and directories currently installed.)
> Unpacking virtualbox-4.2 (from .../virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb) ...
> locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
> locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
> locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
> xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
> dpkg-deb (subprocess): subprocess data returned error exit status 1
> dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
> dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe
> dpkg: error processing /home/anujsharma/Desktop/virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb
> ```
>
> (--install):
>        short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./usr/share/doc/virtualbox-4.2/VirtualBox.chm'
>       Processing triggers for ureadahead ...

Every time this is happening dont know why..
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It really seems your package is corrupt, maybe a problem downloading it? Download it again from [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/). Then take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). Basically you will use md5sum to check the file is oki.  MD5sum makes a hash which calculates if a file is sane. Is very important to use it when you burn an iso image you hope to use for install/repair a system for example.

> md5sum virtualbox-4.2_4.2.16-86992~Ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb

Check if the output is the same number as the one contained  [here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.16/MD5SUMS).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install it from the Ubuntu Software Center?  It available there.

[image]

Or just click [**VirtualBox** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/)